# Peformance difference between single memcache get & multikey get with php?

Tags: php, performance, caching, memcached

I am using memcache for caching layer and i connect to it using [php memcache client](http://php.net/manual/en/class.memcache.php).

So if i need to fetch 2 keys then i can do this in following two ways:

**First:**

```
$memcache_obj = new Memcache;
$memcache_obj->connect('memcache_host', 11211);

$var1 = $memcache_obj->get('key_one');

$var2 = $memcache_obj->get('key_two');
```

**Second**

```
$memcache_obj = new Memcache;
$memcache_obj->connect('memcache_host', 11211);
$var = $memcache_obj->get(Array('key_one', 'key_two'));
```

So my question is will i get any performance benefit in the second approach or internally php memcache client still make two connection requests  to memcache server?

On memcache command level we can get multiple keys in a single command but not sure php client.

Comment: I would *hope* it would make a single request. [`Memcache.get` supports it](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewCommands#get), and it would save the overhead of a second request. But the PHP documentation isn't clear whether it is implemented that way.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes because of PHP documentation i am also confused.

Comment: Why not try and test it out and see what measurable performance difference you get in YOUR environment?

Comment: And/or use a tool like Wireshark to see whether one or two requests are sent.